# Value of pseudo inline-grid-field field - Silverstripe 3 & GridFieldExtensions

Tags: silverstripe

I use SilverStripe GridFieldExtesions for Inline Editing. I create the fields for that dynamically, so they don't exist as database fields and are always empty after saving / opening the object.

```
$i = 1;
$inline_fields = array();

do {
    $field = 'Content' . $i;
    $title = 'Spalte ' . $i;

    $inline_fields[$field] = array(
       'title' => $title,
       'field' => 'TextField'
    );

    $i++;
} while( $i <= $this->Columns );
```

Is there a way to define a value of an inline field like on other fields `TextField::create('Foo', 'Foo', 'Bar')` ?

**Edit:**

So I'll try to explain everything a little bit more clear.
I've got the Objects 'Table' and 'Row'.

On 'Table' you can define how many columns a 'Row' should have. According to the number of columns on 'Table', InlineFields for 'Row' a generated like shown above.

But 'Row' hast only one field called 'Content', because I don't know how many columns the user would like to have. Because of that, I store everything put into 'Content1, Content2, Content3, ...' as imploded array in 'Content'.

So far so good, but I need to display back the users content in the 'Content1, Content2, Content3, ...' fields. If those fields wouldn't be inline-fields, I would do this like that  `TextField::create(Name, Title, Value)`

So I need to find a way to display pre filled content into an inline field.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do and what the problem is. Can you elaborate on that a little please? Maybe give an example.

Comment: Ok, i'll try to make everything a little bit more clear

Answer (score 2):

In the `setDisplayFields` function you can specify a `callback` function that will return the field you want to use.

To use this you would modify your `$inline_fields` array to call this callback:

```
$inline_fields[$field] = array(
    'title' => $title,
    'callback' => 'CustomPage::customContentField'
);
```

In your class create the callback function that will return the field to be used:

```
static function customContentField($record, $col, $grid) {
    $value = '123';
    $field = TextField::create($col, $col, $value);
    return $field;
}
```

This allows you to specify the `$value`. However, this will not function how you want. Setting the `$value` in a `TextField` sets the default value. If you are loading an existing row  the `$value` is not used.

So what happens with this code is when you create a new row it will use the `$value` specified, but after saving the page the `$value` will not be used.

Comment: so sadly this doesn't solve my problem. Now you know what I'd like to do. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: One way could be to use custom JS to get the content into the fields? What do you think.

Comment: That might be possible. Or there might be another way. I'll have a look around when I have some time and see if I can find another way to load the data in.

Comment: thanks a lot. Till than I could use the JS way. I completed the [function](http://www.sspaste.com/paste/show/549879bf20505) to load the content into the fields, now I just need to [hook into the PageLoaded observer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609635/howto-hook-into-pageloaded-observer-in-silverstripe-3) and this way would work.